# How To Show ListView Data Source As Images Slider On ASCX?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I am working on a DotNetNuke project where I have to show some images from the SQL server database on the front end as a slider. I have enclosed the slider markup in `asp:ListView` control on ASCX page and have assigned a dataset as the data source for the `asp:ListView` in my code behind file.

The code is working fine but I need the images to be shown as a slider. Currently, the 2nd image is shown right at the bottom of the first image and 3rd image after the 2nd one. I want them like a slider which slides from right to left or vice versa with navigation buttons on the left and right side.

Here is my ASCX code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvFeaturedSlider" runat="server" class="full">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="home-slide">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="project-title-large">MARRIOT HOTEL LOUNGE</span>   
                <img src="http://localhost:52829<%# Eval("Image") %>" alt="">
            </a>
         </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And here is my code behind code:

```
private void BindSlider()
   {
        ProjectsController objController = new ProjectsController();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = objController.GetFeaturedProjectSlider();

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lvFeaturedSlider.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            lvFeaturedSlider.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            lvFeaturedSlider.DataSource = null;
            lvFeaturedSlider.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

The navigation buttons on left and right are appearing when I hard code the markup outside ItemTemplate. But upon binding, they are not appearing and images are also not showing like a slider. I have tried enclosing the code inside ItemTemplate in a foreach statement but I can't figure out the exact format of how the items are located on ASCX page.

Answer (score 0):

I know that stackoverflow frowns on answering questions by changing the subject, but ... I think that's appropriate here.

First question: Are you doing this in your theme(skin) file? If you are that's not the normal way of doing this.

Second question: Are you storing images in the DNN database?  Generally that's frowned on, mainly for performance issues.

---

Now the right way to go about this is to install a module in your DNN installation and use it's UI and tools to configure the slider.  All of that should be part of the module.  There are some very good slider modules, both commercial and open source.  Google, or check the DNN Store.

---

Now to your question.  Your repeater creates a series of divs on your page, one for each image. That is why you see all of the images in a vertical layout.  If you want to "slide" them, you need to add some functionality to do that. They way that is done is by adding some javascript or jQuery to turn that set of divs into a slider.  Google 'jquery slider' for a lot of choices.

If you use a module that's already been developed, all of this stuff will have been done for you.  You only need to supply the images, and perhaps other stuff, too.